# Show dialog using scriptmanager.registerstartupscript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnNotB" runat="server" OnCommand="showIds" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

And:

```
protected void showIds(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
....
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "UniqueKey", "ShowAllIds();", true);
....
}
```

The Javascript:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
            function ShowAllIds() {
                $("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: 'auto',
                    width: 'auto',
                    draggable: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    modal: true
                });
            }
  </script>
```

How can I get the dialog to be displayed?

Comment: check your console for errors

Comment: you call dialog box for the second time,remove that

Comment: 1. remove second call of $("#dialog").dialog();          2. function SowAllIds(){     $( document ).ready(function() {
     $("#dialog").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: 'auto',
                    width: 'auto',
                    draggable: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    modal: true
                });
});                              3. If document ready will not trigger your dialog then it means ShowAllIds() isn't called, check this by adding alert() or somehitg in first line of code in method.

Comment: I already tried that, no success... still the dialog isn't showing up

Comment: did you added jquery ui after jquery?

Comment: First try to alert simple "hello world" message using this. and check if this is working. I think you might be breaking javascript somewhere. This will help you to know your Jquery is loading and your script is registered too

Answer (score 0):

You have set `autoOpen: false`. Remove it from your code.

Documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-autoOpen

Comment: Still not working... my code from js: <script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowAllIds() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            height: 'auto',
            width: 'auto',
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true
        });
    }
</script>